# Controlling Access subnets from aws vpn connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-vpc

By default when you use the VPN connection that provided by AWS using Customer Gateway and VPG, it give access to all of your vpc, how we can control this access or limit it to only single subnet.

Comment: Can't you control the routing at Customer Gateway? Only route the traffic for subnet to CG. For example, instead of routing `10.0.0.0/16` to CG, route only`10.0.1.0/24`

Comment: helloV, your comment is the answer. There are many choices but I would go with your solution for my network configurations.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a VPN connection, you have the choice between static and BGP.  Further, if you choose to use BGP, you propagate the advertised routes into the VPC.

But even if you're using BGP, you can choose not to propagate the routes, and manually manage the routes in the VPC.

So you can create a route per subnet, and if you want a subnet to have access to the servers on the other side of the VPN, you can add the appropriate routes to that route table.

Comment: This only affects the route from the subnet in the VPC towards the CGW. The trip back would have full access to the VPC so it does not really answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate your VPN connection on a TGW which then can have individual routes to separate VPCs.

[image: TGW routes]